# How to write a continuous (infinite loop) program in JAVA to verify vowel?

Tags: java

Write a program that asks the user to type a vowel from the keyboard. If the character entered is a vowel, display “OK”; if it is not a vowel, display an error message. Be sure to allow both uppercase and lowercase vowels. The program continues until the user types ‘!’.

**I have written the program but I need it to loop. I wrote a code where it only accepts one input and I don't know what I am supposed to use for the input for char.**

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter an alphabet between a to z; Enter ! to stop");
int myChar;
myChar = input.nextInt();

while (myChar <= 'z') {
    if (myChar == 'a' || myChar == 'e' || myChar == 'i' ||myChar == 'o' || myChar == 'u' ) {
        System.out.println(myChar + " OK");
    } else {
        System.out.println(myChar + " is not vowel");    
    }
}
```

Comment: All questions implicitly ask for assistance. A more informative title would be "how do I use a loop instead of my current conditional".

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there :)

A small error that you've made is that you've limited your scanner to only reading integers.

You've also declared myChar to an int. Since it is a character, you can declare it like:

`char myChar = input.next().charAt(0);`

A scanner has many functions, and some are specific to certain variable types

`.nextInt()` will only read integers.
`nextDouble()`.will read doubles
`.nextLine()` will read till the end of the current line

Thus, as I mentioned above, you can simply use `.next().charAt(0)`

Comment: ```.next()``` take in a string... How does it work for a char...? Do you mean ```.next().charAt(0)```?

Comment: Upvote, by the way, I think you missed a code fence...

Comment: You caught me! Thanks for the upvote man :) Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to put the declaration before you give it a value, so it should be

```
int myChar;
myChar = input.nextInt();
```

Second, you are reading a char, so it should not be `int myChar`...

```
char myChar;
myChar = input.next().charAt(0);// Since there no nextChar() in scanner
```

Third, your while loops is NEVER going to stop, since the value of `myChar` is not changed in the while loop,

Fourth, you did not allow both uppercase and lowercase vowels, you only allowed lowercase vowels

Fifth, add the statement "! to stop", I mean, I'm sure you don't want "! is not a vowel" to be printed, right?

So this is what it should look like:

```
Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("enter alphabet between a  & z, ! to stop");
char myChar;
myChar = input.next().charAt(0);

while(('a' <= myChar  && myChar <= 'z') || ('A' <= myChar && myChar <= 'Z')) {
    
    if(myChar == 'a' || myChar == 'e' || myChar == 'i' ||myChar == 'o' || myChar == 'u' || myChar == 'A' || myChar == 'E' || myChar == 'I' || myChar == 'O' || myChar == 'U'){
        System.out.println(myChar + " OK");
    }else if(myChar == '!'){
        break;
    }else{
        System.out.println(myChar + " is not vowel");    
    }
    System.out.println("Enter again:");
    myChar = input.next().charAt(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You code is almost correct but you are missing few very important parts.

1. Declaration `int myChar;` should be written before initialization `myChar = input.nextInt();`
2. You are willing to read a `char` so you should declare `myChar` variable with data type `char` and not `int`.
3. Your `while-loop` condition does not satisfy the need. Because you are just using one end of the range of alphabet but missing the other end and hence it will not generate desired boolean result.

---

Approach to reach solution for your problem:

1. Read a string from user using `scanner.next()` method.
2. Convert the string to lower case to handle upper and lower case vowels.
3. Take the first character from the read string input by using the method `string.charAt(0)` to convert `String` into `char` and save it to `myChar`.
4. Start a `while-loop` that will keep iterating until `myChar == '!'`.
5. Inside the loop, first check if `myChar` is a vowel. If `true`, print "OK".
6. If `myChar` is not a vowel, check if `myChar` fall in range of an alphabet or not. If `true`, print "Not a vowel".
7. If `myChar` does not fall in the range of English alphabets then print "You entered an incorrect alphabet" and prompt for new value.
8. Finally, if `myChar` is `!`, then the condition for `while-loop` becomes false and the program stops.

---

Here is the full code:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter an alphabet between 'a' to 'z'; Enter '!' to terminate");
/*
 * input.next() reads a string from Scanner's input stream until it finds a space or endOfLine.
 * string.toLowerCase() converts any English alphabet in a string to lower case and return the new string. For example, "Hello World 21F" becomes "hello world 21f".
 * string.charAt(0) returns the character of a string at index 0; 1st position.
 */
char myChar = input.next().toLowerCase().charAt(0);

while (myChar != '!') {
    if (myChar == 'a' || myChar == 'e' || myChar == 'i' ||myChar == 'o' || myChar == 'u') {
        System.out.println(myChar + " OK");
    } else if (myChar >= 'a' && myChar <= 'z') {
        System.out.println(myChar + " is not vowel");    
    } else {
        System.err.printf("You entered an incorrect alphabet '%c'. ", myChar);
    }
    System.out.println("Enter an alphabet between 'a' to 'z'; Enter '!' to terminate");
    myChar = input.next().toLowerCase().charAt(0);
}
```